# Add wordpress meta box for all types of posts

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a wordpress plugin and want to add a meta_box for all types of posts ('page', 'post', 'custom_post_type'). By referring the wordpress [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) I found it accepts only single type of post. Does anybody know how to do what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ( array( 'post', 'page', 'custom_whatever', 'whatever2' ) as $page )
    add_meta_box( 'id', 'whatever', $callback, $page, $context, $priority, $callback_args );
```

Note that now $page becomes an array, and ittirating through it , will get you all post types.

**Update I**

You can get all the registered post types with [get_post_types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) and use it to populate the above array.

(note : you might need to filter and get attachments out of the array..)

Comment: Thanks Obmerk. But I want kind of more abstract one where I cannot define what are the custom post types, and works for all post types.

Comment: well - then use 'get_posts_types' to populate the array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full working code.

```
<?php

    function my_meta_box() {

        $my_post_types = get_post_types();

        foreach ( $my_post_types as $my_post_type ) {
            add_meta_box( 
                'Meta_box_ID', __( 'Title of the meta box', 'textdomain' ), 'callback_function', $my_post_type
            );
        }
    }

    function callback_function(){

        // Your metabox code goes here :)

        }

    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_meta_box' );

?>
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Answer (score -1):

Why so elaborate?
Actions are called on every request and the `$post` object is global so we can use that:

```
function my_meta_box() {
    global $post;

    add_meta_box(
        "box-id",
        __("Title"), function () {},
        $post->post_type,
        "context");
}

add_action("add_meta_boxes", "my_add_meta_box");
```